# Python: save reference to a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, reference

An object starts a thread, the object is destroyed but the thread keeps running.

How can I store a reference to that thread so I can interact with it later?

Passing the thread object around is not possible, I don't have access to overlying code.
I managed to get the address of a thread-function but python doesn't allow calling addresses.

Comment: How do you want to interact with it?

Comment: the easiest way is to change some variables of the thread.
or with a setter function that fills a queue in the thread object with the received commands.