# How to store a reference to a ruby thread?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency

I need to construct a thread pool to connect with different servers, but I need to *name* the connections to reuse the connection I need in each case, the problem is that I cannot store references to the threads.

More detailed explanation:

I start a thread (because I've received a request for example), in that thread I make a new connection to server 'A' and do something there, after that, I have a response to my client. When I finish the request the thread finished.

After a while I get a new request from a client and in that request I want to reuse the same connection I was using before, but I have no reference to it.

What I would like is to store a reference to each alive connection to be able to reuse those across the threads.

The solutions I've checked were:

[connection_pool](https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool) treats all the connections equal, and I need to handle different connections.

[agent (concurrent-ruby)](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/Agent.html) doesn't explain how to store agents for reuse.

[thread_pools (concurrent-ruby)](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/file.thread_pools.html) seems to solve the problem of reusing threads, but lack the option to select which thread to re-use.

Comment: A similar question is been asked here about python threads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26444806/python-save-reference-to-a-thread

Comment: If you control what the threads do, can't you store a reference to objects created within the thread? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Why would you want to hold open a connection?

Comment: @engineersmnky because persistent connections should perform better when making lots of small requests.

Comment: If you are making small requests than a thread is unnecessary and your question states "After a while" which does not sound like "lots". *"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"*

Comment: @engineersmnky good point

Comment: @Max what you say makes total sense, thanks

Comment: Why can't you store references to the threads? Threads are objects in Ruby, just like any other object. You can store a reference to a thread the same way you can store a reference to `'Hello'`.

Comment: Reading your question, I assume you want to reply with the same result to connection B, what your server returned for connection A. If that is the case, you can always cache those results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was missing an obvious thing, within ruby variables are not thread local by default (this are [thread variables](http://devdocs.io/ruby~2.5/thread#method-i-thread_variables) for).

Given that the obvious way to store a connection, a thread or a anything between threads is having an object with references.

```
Connections = Hash.new do |hash, server|
  hash[sever] = establish_connection(server)
end

# after that, within any thread I can get a connection to server 'A'
connection = Connections['A']
```

This is not thread safe, but that can be fixed using a `Mutex`.